# UISplitViewController does not show my DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have used UISplitViewController on Storyboard, i have set UINavigationController both for master and detail viewcontroller. Master ViewController is loaded, but Detail ViewController does not load.

I could not figure out what might be wrong?

Could you please help me?

My code on AppDelegate is as follows;

```
 if([Utils isIpad])
 {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitViewController"];
    //UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationViewControllerMaster"];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];    
}
```

Comment: Why did you set navigationController as a rootViewController? I think it should be splitViewController, but is it not set as a initial view controller in your storyboard?

Comment: @BartoszBialecki i have already changed to splitViewController, but now it has started to crash.

Comment: What do you have in your storyboard? If you have there set split view controller as an initial view controller then you should delete setting root view controller from the AppDelegate.